# How to save custom taxonomy archive as a page template?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, page-template

I am working with a custom post type (slug: `estate_property`) which has three custom taxonomies to organize posts (slugs: `estate_type`, `estate_status`, `estate_location`).

I created custom taxonomy archives for all of those to display only posts from the respective taxonomy, which works without problems (e.g. `taxonomy-estate_status.php`). The example of the 'status' taxonomy includes 2 terms: 'rent' and 'sale'. So the respective archive listings can be called via:

`http://localhost/estate/estate_status/sale/`

and

`http://localhost/estate/estate_status/rent/`.

Now, how can I create a page template of the custom taxonomy archives?

I would like to create a page for the menu that displays every taxonomy term. I tried to change the respective permanlink, but it only allows to enter longer URLs (`/estate_status/sale/`, only `/estate_status/`).

I already tried to create a page like `page-taxonomy-estate_type.php`, which is not working.

Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: what is `estate` in those paths? is that a page? and you want `estate/estate_status/` to show a list of terms in the `estate_status` taxonomy? I don't understand the "I tried to change the permalink.." bit.

Comment: `estate` is just the directory of the project on my localhost. In the backend if you edit a page, you have an option to edit the permalink. I want to assign a specific custom taxonomy archive to a specific page, so that I can display that page as a menu item. For e.g. page 'Sale' should display the taxonomy archive for `estate_status` with the term `sale`.

Comment: you can display taxonomy terms as menu items, you don't need to make them a page.

Comment: @user3046831 When creating your menu ( using built in Menus ) could you just add a custom link ( Links section on left of the menus page ) with a relative path to your taxonomy archive? Give it the name of "Sales"?

Comment: Ok, I just found the option that was too easy... And I had started to write a redirect function in functions.php... ;) Sometimes the things are easier then I thought... Thanks a lot. Problem solved.